# Adobe Build Windows 8 phone

Tags: cordova, adobe

I am using Adobe Build (https://build.phonegap.com/) to create my apps but need to get Windows  Phone working. I have tried to install it using the link from Adobe Build but I get "Search for app in the store?" message. iPhone and Android install from the link without a problem.

Any ideas?